# C++ Template Specialization Concept

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I'm exploring C++ Template Specialization, and I'm trying to understand the syntax rules:

```
template <typename T> T foo(T a, char b) {
   /* some code */
}

template <> _X foo<_Y>(_Z a, _W b) {
   /* some code */
}
```

take as an example my simple example with the _X, _Y, _Z, _W as type placeholders.
It seems to me that if I specified the types _Z and _W, why do I need the _Y inside the <_Y>?
and does _Y has to be identical to _Z or _W types?

Regardless of the implementation - I'm trying to understand every tutorial in this topic but it is never explained properly (or maybe it's just me :) ) -
If I already defined a specialized template for certain types, why isn't it enough to call the template function with those types? why do I need to have the _Y type?

why do I need to call the specialized template like this: foo<_Y>(c, d)
and why foo(c, d) is not enough?

Also, from all the testing I have been doing it seems that all types:
_X, _Y, _Z, _W must be identical otherwise I get a build error.
Is that really the case?

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: `_Y` indicates what specific value of `T` your specialization is for. `_X`, `_Z` and `_W` must match what those types would be in the primary template when `T==_Y`, or else you'd have a compiler error.

Comment: @BoP The declaration begins with `template<>`, so it is always an explicit specialization.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. As long as the template arguments can be deduced as in a function call, you can leave out an explicit template argument list.

For example

```
template <> int foo(int a, char b) {
   /* some code */
}
```

works as explicit specialization of `foo<int>`, because the argument for `T` in the primary template can be deduced to `int` from the first function parameter in the specialization, the same way it would be if you made a function call `foo(0, '0')` (type of `0` is `int` and type of `'0'` is `char`), where you also don't have to write `foo<int>(0, '0')` explicitly.

However, in order to match the primary template `_W` must always be `char`. Similarly `_X` and `_Z` (and if given `_Y`) must all be the same type.